# Python how to use .pack for an other monitor resolution?

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi i can't solve this problem, i created a program in a 1920x1080 resolution monitor and when i run it on purpose on an other pc with 1366x768 resolution the position of the Labels is different, i picked the height that should be 768 in one case and 1080 in the other case with:

```
larghezza = window.winfo_screenheight()
```

and used in the pack placements:

```
bottone_reset.pack(side=BOTTOM,anchor=S,pady=(0,altezza*0.1))
bottone_premi.pack(side=BOTTOM,anchor=S,pady=(0,altezza*0.2))
etichetta_click.pack(side=BOTTOM,anchor=S,pady=(0,altezza*0.1))
etichetta_titolo.pack(side=BOTTOM,anchor=S,pady=(0,altezza*0.1))
```

Because in this way the formula changes according to the current monitor resolution but the Labels are still in a different position, how to handle this ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem being that the location of the buttons and label changes based on window size. You're trying to modify the positioning manually based on the window size. While ingenious, it's obviously not working as you intend. There are, however, different options other than pack(). These are [grid()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-grid-method-in-tkinter/) and [place()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-place-method-in-tkinter/).
(Links go to "geeksforgeeks" website, which is what I'm currently using as reference.)

'**grid()**' places elements in a grid using columns and rows, and is best used for elements that have the same dimensions (at least in the direction you're placing them, so if you want them all aligned on the X direction, they should have similar length to not look weird).

```
bottone_reset.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
bottone_premi.grid(column = 1, row = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
etichetta_click.grid(column = 2, row = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
etichetta_titolo.grid(column = 3, row = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
```

'**place()**' lets you determine the explicit location of something, which can be useful but in case of your choice of element placement would likely not help, since if the window shortens, place will not change location.

---

I would suggest creating a frame for the elements listed, then depending on what is most useful to you, use pack() or grid() to place the elements within that frame. In turn, place that frame where you want the buttons to end up.

```
frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor = S)

bottone_reset = Button(frame,text = "reset")
bottone_premi = Button(frame, text = "premi")
etichetta_click = Label(frame, text = "click")
etichetta_titolo = Label(frame, text = "Title")
```

Ofc, your definition of the buttons and labels will look different, these are just placeholders.

---

The following code will always place the buttons in the bottom center of the window, regardless of what size that screen is (unless the total elements no longer fit). It's closest to what I could see you were trying to attempt. of course, you'll have to replace my manual input of window width and height with your screen size detection. I could not immediately get that to work with just tkinter, so I decided to change values manually.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Pack Problem")

windowWidth = 1000
windowHeight = 768
windowSize = str(windowWidth) + "x" + str(windowHeight)
window.geometry(windowSize)

frame = Frame()
frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, anchor = S)

bottone_reset = Button(frame,text = "reset")
bottone_premi = Button(frame, text = "premi")
etichetta_click = Label(frame, text = "click")
etichetta_titolo = Label(frame, text = "Title")

bottone_reset.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
bottone_premi.grid(column = 1, row = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
etichetta_click.grid(column = 2, row = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)
etichetta_titolo.grid(column = 3, row = 0, padx = 5, pady = 5)


window.mainloop()
```

The layout and makeup are obviously just placeholders, but this should function as a framework for what you want to do.

**EDIT**: With a better understanding of the problem, different approach. Leaving the original comment for those that could use it.

In order to change padding size based upon resolution, the fastest way I can think of is to bind a resize function to window configuration.

```
window.bind('<Configure>', function)
```

Sadly, attempts to make it a smooth adjustment have not been successful so far. I'll leave that up to you to attempt if you wish.
The solution I've gotten to work is this:

```
def padsize(e):


    if e.height <= 1080 and e.height > 768:
        bottone_reset.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=25, pady=25)
        bottone_premi.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=25, pady=25)
        etichetta_click.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=25, pady=25)
        etichetta_titolo.grid(column=3, row=0, padx=25, pady=25)
        #print("window height is larger than 768")
    elif e.height <768 and e.height > 640:
        bottone_reset.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        bottone_premi.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        etichetta_click.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        etichetta_titolo.grid(column=3, row=0, padx=15, pady=15)
        #print("window height is larger than 768")
    elif e.height <640 and e.height > 250:
        bottone_reset.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        bottone_premi.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        etichetta_click.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        etichetta_titolo.grid(column=3, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        #print("window height is smaller than 768")
window.bind('<Configure>', padsize)
```

As you can see, I made the pad size differences really drastic, in order to be able to see the change rather than needing a ruler to check. It should be far less noticeable at smaller size differences.

Comment: Hi Ivain thanks a lot for the complete answer, i read all and basically the problem is not the windows size, i run it maximized but it's not that the problem. You suggest to bind the Labels and Buttons on a frame and i did it, but it's the same result because i think that for example i write "pady = 30" but 30 pixels in a 1920x1080 monitor are for example 5 centimeters and in a 1366x767 monitor are 3 centimeters for example, so the position in the final result is different, i can't add imagese because i'm new.

Comment: Basically i need a different pady value according to the monitor i'm running the program, in this way the position is the same in proportions, any other solution? Otherwhise i'm stuck with programs that i'm sure can run as i programmed only in my resolution please help :/

Comment: Ah, makes sense, I wasn't entirely sure what you were going for, for some reason I didn't quite interpret what variables you were adapting to the screen size correctly.
Having now set the res of each of my monitors to the resolutions you're using, I see the problem.

Fastest way to do this is to bind a function to resizing the window. ``` window.bind('<Configure>', function) ```. I'll update my comment with the code I use when I finish testing if my approach works.

Comment: Got something working. As said in the post edit, it's hardly a smooth transition, or an elegant solution in general, but it will definitely change the value of the padding based on the resolution (in this case via window height). There's probably still a lot of work to be done on your end to get the results you want, but I hope this will at least let you get started in the right direction.